# Compute the forces affecting a fish swimming in a water in an efficient way, without computing the dynamics of the whole fluid

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, simulations

I wish to implement a computer simulation of fish swimming in water in a best-effort physically accurate way.

I would need this simulation to be *fast*. This means that I can't simulate the dynamics of the whole body of water.

All I need to simulate is the linear and angular position/velocity/acceleration of one fish: how they would change if the fish were moving in water.

I'm happy to simulate the fish in a 2D environment (as seen from above), as the math would probably be much simpler in this case.

###### What I have in mind

I'm thinking about using a rigid-body physics engine to model the simulate world and the physics of the fish, and compute by myself the forces that would affect a fish as it wriggles:

- The simulated world would update at a discretized time interval, for instance 10 milliseconds per time step.
- A fish body could be approximated by a number of rigid bodies connected by joints which allow these rigid bodies to rotate relatively to each other (or any other way, if there are simpler ones).

  - I'm thinking it could be modeled as one or two rigid bodies for the side fins and a chain of rigid bodies for the main part of the fish extending to the rear fin.
  - Each rigid body could be described by the shape of the 2D section, its height and its density, from which I can compute volume, surface area, mass etc.
  - Each joint would basically be a "muscle". I can apply a torque on the joint causing part of the fish to "wriggle".
- At every time step, if part of the fish moves, I need to compute the forces the fish is subject to and update linear and angular velocity in a way as physically realistic as possible.

###### Problem & Question

In order to achieve what I described above, I need to define the formulas that govern the fish body based on the velocity and physical properties of each rigid body of the fish.

Let's say that one rigid body of the fish (e.g. part of a fin) rotates around its joint. I know how much it rotates by, its physical properties (section, surface area, mass etc) as well as how it relates to the rest of the fish body. I basically know everything... How do I compute which forces this causes the fish to be subject to?

I don't know how to come up with the formulas I need. Have similar forces been studied and described somewhere? Otherwise how could I go to try and define them myself? I'd love to find related resources of any kind to help me with this problem.

---

I posted a similar question to GameDev (https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/205440/156629) and they recommended to look at hydrodynamics. I hope this post fits here.

---

The question was closed because it "need focus". According to https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions, that means:

- **Needs more focus** - If your question has many valid answers (but no way to determine which, if any, are correct), then it probably needs to be more focused to be successful in our format.

  > This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

  This can often be fixed by breaking the post into multiple questions, or by focusing on a specific part of the problem.

I believe this question is already focused and cannot be broken into multiple ones, thus I'm reopening it.

If you disagree with my assessment please explain with a comment what's wrong with the focus of this question. I'll be very happy to post a thousand other tinier questions each focusing on a smaller detail if that's the wish of this community. But I simply would not know how to break it up.

Comment: Swimming is a surprisingly complicated action.  If you put a bunch of effort into modeling the physics, be ready to spend even more time working through the control theory required to make a fish that swims rather than flounders.

Comment: Concerning the breadth of this question:  by my reading your question is "how do I calculate the forces on an object in a fluid?", and the answer is basically "learn hydrodynamics".  I don't think it would practical to give a complete and definitive summary of the subject in this format.  A [tag:resource-recommendations] question like "what sources should I be looking at to solve problems like this?" would probably be OK, as would a more focused question on how to apply specific concepts to your situation.

Comment: As Michael points out, this question is astoundingly broad and would require a lengthy answer to adequately address it, as it covers a wide subject area of biomechanics & fluid dynamics (probably others). Converting this into a "what type of books can I learn from to model this?" question might suffice to reopen it, but otherwise I don't even see how you could break this question down into any subquestions.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at [(Ekeberg 1993)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01185408) which models a fish using segments connected together, and a simplified water model. Given that it was done in 1993, it would be fast on modern computers.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting that paper. I couldn't find a free version and will try to get one from the paper's authors or to look for it further. I could find a number of related articles that cite that paper and seem relevant though. +1 for now. Will approve your answer once I manage to get some formulas through this thread.